# How to delete test orders in magento CE 1.9

Tags: attributes

I want to delete test orders from my magento 1.9 before going live. the script I found was for EE1.9 and contains some table that cannot be found in CE1.9. Please help

Comment: Simply got your database phpMyadmin and then open the table `sales_flat_order `and then simply remove tha data from this tabel and your test orders will be cleared. No need of any code or commands oe extension to install. cool.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create php script in Magento root folder, copy this code into script and run script.
Take db backup before proceeding

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.2.0', '<')===true) {
    echo  '<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"><div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;"><h3 style="margin:0; font-size:1.7em; font-weight:normal; text-transform:none; text-align:left; color:#2f2f2f;">Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.</h3></div><p>Magento supports PHP 5.2.0 or newer. <a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/install" target="">Find out</a> how to install</a> Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.</p></div>';
    exit;
}
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    exit;
}
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();
$executionPath = null;
/*
 * determine Magento Edition
 */
if (file_exists('LICENSE_EE.txt')) {
    $edition = 'EE';
}elseif (file_exists('LICENSE_PRO.html')) {
    $edition = 'PE';
} else {
    $edition = 'CE';
}
if(($edition=='EE' && version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.11.0.0.', '<')===true)
        || ($edition=='PE' && version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.11.0.0.', '<')===true)
        || ($edition=='CE' && version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0.0.', '<')===true)
  ){
   $executionPath = 'old';
} else {
   $executionPath = 'new';
}
$xpathEntity = 'global/models/sales_entity/entities//table';
if ($executionPath == 'old') {
    $xpathResource = 'global/models/sales_mysql4/entities//table';
} else {
    $xpathResource = 'global/models/sales_resource/entities//table';
}
$salesEntitiesConf = array_merge(
    Mage::getSingleton('core/config')->init()->getXpath($xpathEntity),
    Mage::getSingleton('core/config')->init()->getXpath($xpathResource)
);
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
/*
 * If you want delete System/Order Statuses (Status and State) you
 * should comments below lines (46-51)
 */
$skipTables = array (
        $resource->getTableName('sales_order_status'),
        $resource->getTableName('sales_order_status_state'),
        $resource->getTableName('sales_order_status_label')
    );
$salesEntitiesConf = array_diff($salesEntitiesConf, $skipTables);
/*
Multiple RDBMS Support in Magento CE 1.6+ / EE 1.11+
http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RDBMS_Guide2.pdf
2.2. Adapters:
... The new Varien_DB_Adapter_Interface was added to sign a contract that all
developed adapters must execute in order to get Magento working on an actual
database. The interface describes the list of methods and constants that can be used by resource models...
Used below in the loop:
 * If $executionPath == 'old'
    * Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::showTableStatus()
    * Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::truncate()
 * Else
    * Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::isTableExists()
    * Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::truncateTable()
*/
while ($table = current($salesEntitiesConf) ){
    $table = $resource->getTableName($table);
    if ($executionPath == 'old') {
        $isTableExists = $connection->showTableStatus($table);
    } else {
        $isTableExists = $connection->isTableExists($table);
    }
    if ($isTableExists) {
        try {
            if ($executionPath == 'old') {
                $connection->truncate($table);
            } else {
                $connection->truncateTable($table);
            }
            printf('Successfully truncated the <i style="color:green;">%s</i> table.<br />', $table);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            printf('Error <i style="color:red;">%s</i> occurred truncating the <i style="color:red;">%s</i> table.<br />', $e->getMessage(), $table);
        }
    }
    next($salesEntitiesConf);
}
exit('All done...');
```

Comment: Simply got your database phpMyadmin and then open the `table sales_flat_order `and then simply remove tha data from this tabel and your test orders will be cleared. No need of any code or commands. cool.

Answer (score 0):

There is a FREE extension you can use http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/seamless-delete-order.html. It is working on Magento v1.9

Comment: Simply got your database phpMyadmin and then open the table `sales_flat_order `and then simply remove tha data from this tabel and your test orders will be cleared. No need of any code or commands. cool.

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution for CE 1.9.0.1. I have **NOT** tested it on any other version.

I'm not a great fan of editting in the core. But here is how you can add the delelte button on an order. Havent made a massDelte method yet, might do that some other time.

Go to:
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php

comment line 45:

```
// $this->_removeButton('delete');
```

Go to:
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php

Add this method:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->delete();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order has been deleted.')
            );
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order has not been deleted.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

This is a solution for CE 1.9.0.1. I have **NOT** tested it on any other version.

PS. It's best to use this for your test orders and disable it. Don't let your clients have this feature, you don't want them to delete an order on accident by hitting the wrong button.

Comment: There's no need to edit the core for this.

Comment: Well that's true. But this is the fastest way to delete a few orders since im only using this feature to delete some test orders when the site is about te be released to the client.

Comment: Why don't you just delete all test data (incl. all orders) when the website goes online?